# How to dynamically fetch rows by referencing the table and row id from incoming flow files in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

In my use case I will have a hbase table from where I will be reading incrementsal records using getHbase and one of the value from that record should be should be used as a input to FetchHBaseRow processor. So how can i access the file content from the flow file and use it as input to FetchHbaseRow.

Answer (score 5):

You can have `GetHBase` and connect it to `EvaluateJsonPath` (since GetHBase outputs the result in JSON format) to get Row ID and then use the Row ID in `FetchHBaseRow` by setting the dynamic attribute name used in EvalueteJsonPath in the `Row Identifier` property in FetchHBaseRow.

In my example, I have mentioned `EvaluateJsonPath` is used to read the row key, but you can use a valid Json Path expression to read any values from the GetHBase output and use it.

**Sample Flow**

[image: Sample Flow]

**Reading Row Key**

Using EvaluateJsonPath, we are reading the row key from the JSON output by the `GetHBase` processor. Ensure that `Destination` is set to `flowfile-attribute`

[image: Reading Row Key]

**Using the parsed Row key**

We read the row key and put it in the `row.key` attribute. Here, we are using that attribute in the property `Row Identifier` in `FetchHBaseRow`

[image: Using parsed Row key]

Comment: I think the first image does not really fit to the described process, but I understood the process. Unfortunately this process is quite inefficient because it will create network traffic twice for the same data. I think there should be some more efficient way to do this, as it blows up especially for large tables.